# How we can publish a twitter dataset?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

We are going to collect records of roughly 80M from twitter but, we do not know if that is legal or illegal to publish it somewhere like Github.
I saw that users, mostly publish the tweet IDs other than the whole tweet data (like text, username and ...). How is possible to publish twitter data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saw that users, mostly publish the tweet IDs other than the whole tweet data

That's correct, and that's aligned with the [Twitter Developer Policy](https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/policy#4-e) that you agree to when using the API, which states:

> If you provide Twitter Content to third parties, including downloadable datasets or via an API, you may only distribute Tweet IDs, Direct Message IDs, and/or User IDs (except as described below). We also grant special permissions to academic researchers sharing Tweet IDs and User IDs for non-commercial research purposes.
> [... - ...]
> Academic researchers are permitted to distribute an unlimited number of Tweet IDs and/or User IDs if they are doing so on behalf of an academic institution and for the sole purpose of non-commercial research. For example, you are permitted to share an unlimited number of Tweet IDs for the purpose of enabling peer review or validation of your research. If you have questions about whether your use case qualifies under this category please submit a request via the [API Policy Support form](https://help.twitter.com/forms/platform).

Basically, if you are in any doubt you should ask Twitter directly via the form linked above, but the policy is pretty clear that you should only be sharing Tweet IDs. You should also have stated your intent when applying for API access.